# How can I find all ascii files under one directory that have the word shirt in them? Starting from root

Tags: find, root, ascii

What command would I use to find all of the files under the girl directory that have the ascii text “shirt” inside the files, starting from the root directory?

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep -FH text
```

Runs faster than either `-exec` or `grep -r` on my machine.

Comment: This is the best answer of the (current) three, because it's a more general technique, it's more portable, and doesn't require memorising `find`s funky syntax.  It's also more flexible, because you can include any number of other filters between the `find` and the `xargs` (by the way, the `-print0` and `-0` are formally correct, but rarely necessary, and usually a pest to type)

Comment: Nice. It won't be faster when there are many binary files, which grep knows how to skip.

@norman-gray `-print0` and `-0` are always necessary for scripts. They live on past the author and can give "wtf" moments when they don't work correctly.

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff Yes, I agree with you about `-print0` in scripts -- it's best to be on one's best behaviour when it's written down for others to see...

Answer (score 4):

`grep` is the standard tool for searching for a pattern inside of files. It has an option for searching recursively, which means if it finds a directory, it goes inside and searches in everything in there.

The command would simply be `grep -r shirt /path/to/girl/`

I also like to add two options that skip files that I know I'm not interested in: `--binary-files=without-match` and `--devices=skip`.

Comment: If you just want a list of files, use `grep -r -l shirt /path/to/girl`.

Comment: Yes, @keith-thompson 's suggestion is faster, also because it will stop scanning once it finds just one match.

Comment: Thank you Shawn J. Goff.  grep -r shirt /path/to/girl/ worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Shawn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23144/how-can-i-find-all-ascii-files-under-one-directory-that-have-the-word-shirt-in-t/23147#23147), using `grep -r` might be enough for your needs.

Otherwise a combination of `find` and `grep` can do the trick:

```
find . -exec grep -H text '{}' ';'
```

This allows to refine the search using specific find predicates.
(And `-H` option is there so that filenames are printed along with the matched content.)